# How can I select deleted code in the diff view of GitKraken?

Tags: gitkraken

How can I select deleted (red) code in GitKraken?

[image]

Comment: Cool when you can create git to desmontrate the issue! May you share what software/tool to do so? Thank u.

Comment: @NamGVU https://getsharex.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't select it if you're in Hunk or Inline views. However, you can select it in Split view.

[image]

If you want to copy a specific deleted line, or all deleted lines in a hunk, you can simply right click it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an open request to add this feature in the Hunk view: https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/197805/copy-deleted-lines-from-diff-view-hunk-inline

Meanwhile, just use Split view, as mentioned above.